# How to make a command block work every 30 seconds?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So im trying to make a command block which activates every 30 seconds. The command in the command block is `/kill @e[type=minecraft:arrow]` so it kills all arrows on the ground every 30 seconds. How can I do that?

Comment: that would also kill in air arrows just to let you know

Answer (score 1):

You can use a so-called [hopper clock](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mechanics/Redstone/Clock_circuit/hopper_clock) to give out a redstone signal every so or so ticks. If you put exactly 38 items in the Ethonian hopper clock, you will get a redstone signal every 304 ticks which is very close to 30 seconds (30.25 seconds).

Diagram:
[image: Ethionian Hopper Clock]

Comment: I'd advise not mixing commands and redstone when not necessary, but this is definitely the best type of redstone clock for long amounts of time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how we can interpret this using another command, but what you can do is to use repeater timing via redstone clocks.

What do I mean by this? Set the command block somewhere and add redstone repeaters and make sure to time the repeaters to somewhere around 29-30 seconds (if it's not that accurate) and you can just activate a single repeater by right-clicking a lever fast 2 times at the command block.

For you to justify this, try using another block (must be solid) and put up the redstone repeaters and time it to 29-30 seconds, and check how long it will take for the lit repeaters to reach the opaque block after activating it quickly.